# How to read data from an XML parsed by Nokogiri in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I want to retrieve the newest video URL from a Youtube RSS feed of a channel.

This is a sample URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feed/videos.xml?channel_id=UCBcRF18a7Qf58cCRy5xuWwQ
```

I am currently using the following code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
youtube_xml = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCBcRF18a7Qf58cCRy5xuWwQ"
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(youtube_xml))
```

How do I get the first video entry URL?
This doesn't work, but for example:

```
first_video_url = xml.feed.entry[0].link
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We'd like to see more effort, showing what you tried, and an example of why it doesn't work. "this doesn't work" tells us nothing. What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

`xml.css('entry link').first.attribute('href').to_s`

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Also, read up on the difference between `css` and `at_css` and `search` and `at`. `css(...).first` is the same as `at_css`. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at-instance_method